# How to Unmarshall data to JSON with unknown field types

Tags: json, api, go, unmarshalling

I have these 'structures'

```
type Results struct {
    Gender string `json:"gender"`
    Name   struct {
        First string `json:"first"`
        Last  string `json:"last"`
    } `json:"name"`
    Location struct {
        Postcode int `json:"postcode"`
    }
    Registered struct {
        Date string `json:"date"`
    } `json:"registered"`
}

type Info struct {
    Seed    string `json:"seed"`
    Results int64  `json:"results"`
    Page    int64  `json:"page"`
    Version string `json:"version"`
}

type Response struct {
    Results []Results `json:"results"`
    Info    Info      `json:"info"`
}
```

I' making a request to an external API and converting data to a JSON view.
I know in advance the types of all fields, but the problem occurs with the 'postcode' field. I'm getting different types of values, which is why I get a JSON decoding error.
In this case, 'postcode' can be one of three variants:

1. string ~ "13353"
2. int ~ 13353
3. string ~ "13353postcode"

Changing the `postcode` type from `string` to `json.Number` solved the problem.
But this solution does not satisfy the third "option".

I know I can try to create a custom type and implement an interface on it. Seems to me the best solution using `json.RawMessage`. It’s the first I've faced this problem, So I'm still looking for an implementation of a solution to this and reading the documentation.

What's the best way solution in this case?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a custom string type and have it implement the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface.

For example, you could do this:

```golang
type PostCodeString string

// UnmarshalJSON implements the json.Unmarshaler interface.
func (s *PostCodeString) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if data[0] != '"' { // not string, so probably int, make it a string by wrapping it in double quotes
        data = []byte(`"`+string(data)+`"`)
    }

    // unmarshal as plain string
    return json.Unmarshal(data, (*string)(s))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pp-zNNWY38M

Comment: This is a great solution, but I'm not getting an array of strings from the API.
Sample response (Sorry if poorly readable in comments):
`{ "results": [ { "name": { "first": "Aurélien", "last": "Andre" }, "location": { "postcode": 58499 } }, { "name": { "first": "Endre", "last": "Gjerdrum" }, "location": { "postcode": "5018" } }, { "name": { "first": "Dwight", "last": "Johnson" }, "location": { "postcode": "IM33 4LY" } } ], "info": { "seed": "320731c5fddfed33", "results": 3, "page": 1, "version": "1.3" } }`
Therefore, I do not quite understand how to use your solution in my case.

Comment: That's just an example to prove the solution can handle all 3 types (integer, string with integer, string with text). You already know how to change `string` to `json.Number`, now do the same thing but instead of changing `string` to `json.Number` change it to `PostCodeString`.